# Meteor Publishing posts and their number of comments

Tags: meteor

I want to publish an array of posts and how many comments each post has. I have been using `publishComposite` thef following way:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('postsAndComments', function (limit) {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});

  return {
    find: function() {
      if (!this.userId) {
        return;
      }

      return Posts.find({
        networkId: user.networkId
      }, {
        sort: {createdAt: -1},
        limit: limit
      });
    },
    children: [
      {
        find: function (post) {
          return Comments.find({postId: post._id});
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

This is inefficient because I don't need to have any field from `comments`. I just need to know `numComments` for each `post`. I would `_.extend()` a `post` object if it were a normal array, but since you have to return a `cursor` object, I am not sure what the best approach is.

For now, I am thinking of limiting the `field` of `comment` to only contain its `_id` and return them along with `posts`.

Comment: I see an issue in the code here in the sense that you limit the output of Posts, which means you will never get the 'real' number of comments, but only the count that you publish.
As Michel suggest, you should also limit the number if fields to only those you need.
ALso take a look at the publish-counts package that does just that, unfortunately does not mix well with publishComposite, but can give you an idea: publish a collection with just counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce the amount of data that needs to go over the wire while retaining the ability to count your comments on the client, you can restrict the number of fields you return from the `Comments` collection:

```
children: [
  {
    find: function (post) {
      return Comments.find({ postId: post._id },{ fields: { _id: 1 }});
    }
  }
]
```

Alternatively you could include a `numComments` key in your `Posts` collection and keep that up to date as comments are added.